# Getting Index -1 requested, with a size of 1 error while fetching data android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am using following code to get version of content

```
public String getNotificationVersion(String rootContentId) {
    String strVersion = "";
    try {
        database.open();
        Cursor cur = database.query(Database.DOWNLOAD_TABLE,
                new String[] { Database.KEY_VERSION },
                Database.KEY_ROOT_CONTENT_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { rootContentId }, null, null, null);
        Log.v("NOTIFICATION PRESENT IN DOWNLOAD GETTING DOWNLOAD", "TRUE");
        strVersion = cur.getString(0);
        cur.close();
        database.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v("NOTIFICATION PRESENT IN DOWNLOAD GETTING DOWNLOAD", e.getMessage());
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return strVersion;
}
```

and at "strVersion = cur.getString(0);" line I am getting Index -1 requested, with a size of 1 error.
I have checked database and there is value for this column. Where I am doing wrong?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You didn't move the cursor to its first record (which index is 0). Therefore, it's still positioned at index -1.

Comment: yes I missed that.. Thanks for your immediate reply

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
Cursor cur = database.query(Database.DOWNLOAD_TABLE,
                new String[] { Database.KEY_VERSION },
                Database.KEY_ROOT_CONTENT_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { rootContentId }, null, null, null);
        Log.v("NOTIFICATION PRESENT IN DOWNLOAD GETTING DOWNLOAD", "TRUE");

        // add this.....
  if (cursor == null) {
        Log.d("Database", "Data empty");
        } 
  else {
        //Move cursor to first record
        cur.moveToFirst();

        // access value
        strVersion = cur.getString(0);
        cur.close();
        database.close();
}
```